# ngx-bootstrap datepicker angular 4

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

Recently upgraded to angular 4.0.3 at one of my projects which uses the ngx-bootstrap datepicker and a warning pops up at console about using templates is deprecated. Does any know if there are plans to move and use ng-template instead?

```
[WARNING ->] template ngFor [ngForOf]="rows" let-rowz="$implicit" let-index="index">
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see here. https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3301

Answer (score 2):

It is fixed as of **2.0.0-beta.2**.

```
 npm i -S ngx-bootstrap@2.0.0-beta.2
```